# Salesforce GraphQL API Pagination: Duplicate Records Returned in Second Page Query

Tags: graphql, salesforce

salesforce graphql api query accounts, for the second page, using previous endCursor for "after" value, return some duplicate records that already show in the first page. I am using v57 api

First page query:

```
query accounts {
  uiapi {
    query {
      Account (first:10) {
        edges {
          node {
            Id
            Name {
              value
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Second page query with cursor:

```
query accounts {
  uiapi {
    query {
      Account (first:10, after:"djE6OQ==") {
        edges {
          node {
            Id
            Name {
              value
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It should work like Offset/Limit in SOQL, but more efficient, why the pagination returns duplicate records that already returned in the previous pages? Is there something wrong in my query?